# How to generate multivalued attribute SAML2 assertion using WSO2 Identity Server 5.3?

Tags: wso2, saml, assertions, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.3

I have to produce a SAML2 assertion with some multivalued attributes from the user profile.

Let's say I have a comma separated list of values for a particular claim and I must organize those attributes using the following structure in my saml assertion response:

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="attribute1">
    <saml2:AttributeValue>value1</saml2:AttributeValue>
    <saml2:AttributeValue>value2</saml2:AttributeValue>
    <saml2:AttributeValue>value3</saml2:AttributeValue>
    <saml2:AttributeValue>value4</saml2:AttributeValue>
</saml2:Attribute>
```

I configured an STS client to get SAML2 assertion and claims from a particular user which I setup with a multivalued claim.

My issue is I get the SAML assertion response as the following structure:

```
<saml2:Attribute Name="attribute1">
    <saml2:AttributeValue>value1,value2,value3,value4</saml2:AttributeValue>
 </saml2:Attribute>
```

I setup an instance of the travelocity application on a tomcat, tested again and I got the SAML assertion as expected after login to the application and choosing the SAML flow. I could verify it looking at the log file of the Identity Server.

I used the STS client [1] as well to get the SAML assertion but what I got when it comes to a multivalued attribute is a comma separated values for that particular attribute.

I went directly towards the admin service https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts?wsdl using SOAP UI as my client but SAML response was the exact same case as I stated before, multivalued attribute comes as a comma separated values for that particular attribute.

Here is a sample of what I get in the Attribute Statement section:

```
<saml2:AttributeStatement>
    <saml2:Attribute Name="http://wso2.org/claims/im" NameFormat="http://wso2.org/claims/im">
        <saml2:AttributeValue
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">jairo_fernandezr,jb_fernandez
        </saml2:AttributeValue>
    </saml2:Attribute>
    <saml2:Attribute Name="http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress" NameFormat="http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress">
        <saml2:AttributeValue
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">jairo.fernandez@chakray.com
        </saml2:AttributeValue>
    </saml2:Attribute>
    <saml2:Attribute Name="http://wso2.org/claims/givenname" NameFormat="http://wso2.org/claims/givenname">
        <saml2:AttributeValue
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Jairo
        </saml2:AttributeValue>
    </saml2:Attribute>
</saml2:AttributeStatement>
```

Now, I would like to ask you if there is another way to get a SAML assertion with multivalued attributes structured as single values instead of a comma separated values using the admin service https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts?wsdl or another approach without setting up the travelocity application.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-is/tree/5.x.x/modules/samples/sts

Any comment will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Indeed using separated values is the default way how the wso2is handles the multi-value attributes. I believe you could implement your own class that creates the saml response (overwrite the method creating attributes from claims) and configure it in  the api-manager.xml (I don't remember the interface exactly, I may check once I get to my office on Monday) . next thing you'd need to overwrite is your own claim handler (that's the class creating key/value map for claims) however I would check how the signature would work with your own implementation..

Comment: What's your user store? Is it the default LDAP?

Comment: I have an external LDAP as the primary user store and also I have an AD as a secondary user store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSO2 Identity server 5.3.0 behaves correctly when it comes to the Web SAML SSO flow.

But the service wso2carbon-sts which can be found by default at  https://localhost:9443/services/wso2carbon-sts behaves differently as I described in my original post.

I have made a report of this to the WSO2 team and they registered a bug in Identity Server's project, you can see details [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-6681) and follow up this if you are interested.

Thanks for your support